# JQuery: $(this) == $("#idVal") returns false but both are exactly same

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand why two jQuery objects are not considered equal. When I pass $(this) to `console.log()` I get:

```
w.fn.init [input#company-center.drop-menu-open]
```

Then when I pass `$("#idVal")` to `console.log()` I get the exact same result:

```
w.fn.init [input#company-center.drop-menu-open]
```

However, when I do `$(this) == $("#idVal")`, it returns false.

Is it because of `==`? Why does it give me `false`?

Comment: `$(document.body) !== $(document.body)` so ... probably because `{} !== {}`

Comment: @BrianPutt - no

Comment: objects are like pennies, you can have two that represent the same thing, but they aren't. You can verify this when you throw one in the well and you still have the other in your pocket ;)  If two objects are the exact same, you could use `Object.is` to determine if two variables point to the same value, but that is fairly rare.  Instead, checking the `id` of `this` is probably your best bet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `$(this) == $("#idVal")` returns `false` is because `$(this)` and `$("#idVal")`) are two distinct object instances (despite the fact they are wrapping the same underlying DOM element).

To determine if the underlying elements of two jQuery objects are equivalent, use `$.is()`:

```
$(this).is("#idVal") // will return true if this is id=idVal
```

[See the documentation on `$.is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `$()` it creates a new jQuery object. Since `==` tests object equality, not content equivalence, they don't compare equal.

You can use the jQuery `.is()` method:

```
$(this).is("#idVal");
```

But you don't even need jQuery for this, just use:

```
this.id == "idVal"
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that internally JavaScript actually has two different approaches for testing equality. Primitives like strings and numbers are compared by their value, while objects like arrays, dates, and plain objects are compared by their reference

[Follow this link for more](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html)